# Is $T(X)$ a sufficient statistic for $\lambda$?

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X$ be a sample (size n = 1) from the exponential distribution, which has the pdf $$f(x;\lambda) = \lambda \exp(-\lambda x)$$ where $\lambda$ is an unknown parameter. Let's define a statistic as

$$T(X)= \left\{ \begin{array}{lcc}
             1  & X > 2 \\
             \\ 0 &\mbox{ otherwise} \\
             \\ 
             \end{array}
   \right.$$

Is $T(X)$ a sufficient statistic for $\lambda$?

I honestly have no idea on how to approach this problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: The classic way to prove something about sufficiency is to try to use the factorization theorem.  If I give you the hint that $T(X) = 1_{X > 2}$, does that help?

Comment: @OldGodzilla, I know $T(X)=1$ but how do I proceed from there?

Comment: It's not that $T(X) = 1$, it's that $T(X)$ is the indicator of an event.  If $T$ is sufficient for $\lambda$, then distribution can be factored into the product of two parts: one depending just on $x$ and one depending only on $\lambda$ and $T(X)$.

Answer (score 0):

Use the definition of sufficiency to prove that a statistic is *not* sufficient; the Factorisation theorem comes in handy when you are proving that a statistic *is* sufficient.

For any $x\geqslant 0$, the distribution function of $X\mid T=1$ is

\begin{align}
P(X\leqslant x\mid T=1)&=\begin{cases}\frac{P(X\leqslant x)}{P(T=1)}&,\text{ if }T=1 \\ \quad 0 &,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}
\\&=\begin{cases}\frac{P(X\leqslant x)}{P(X>2)}&,\text{ if }T=1 \\ \quad 0&,\text{ otherwise }\end{cases}
\end{align}

Can you see now whether the conditional distribution $X\mid T$ depends on $\lambda$ or not? From this information, conclude about the sufficiency of $T$.

Comment: for both cases the conditional distribution  depends on $\lambda$. Would that be sufficient to say that the statistic is not sufficient then?

Comment: @Lady Yes, that's what the definition of *sufficiency* says.

Comment: but why is x defined to be greater than or equal to zero in your definition?

Comment: @Lady Because that is the support of your exponential distribution.

Comment: why use $P(X\leqslant x\mid T=1)$ ?

Comment: can I use $P(X_1=x_1, ..., X_n=x_n\mid T=1)$?

Comment: @Lady The sample size is one. And moreover $X$ is continuous, so that's why we cannot use something like $P(X=x\mid T=1)$.

Comment: did you get this expression as your answer $$P(X\leqslant x\mid T=1) = \frac{1-exp(-\lambda x)}{exp(-2\lambda)}$$?

Comment: @Lady Yes, and note that for all $x\in[0,\infty)$, the distribution $[X\mid T=1]$ depends on $\lambda$, implying that $T$ is not sufficient for $\lambda$.